# Calling c-electric-brace programmatically

Tags: cc-mode, insert, newlines, electric-indent

I'm currently extending the `tempo.el` template insertion system to be sensitive to C styles. Specifically, I want to insert braces using `c-electric-brace`. How programmatically insertion of braces as either `(c-electric-brace "{"))` or `(c-electric-brace "}"))` only results in insertion of a newline but not the brace character itself.

I've also tried `(self-insert-command 1 "{")` and `(progn (self-insert-command 1) (insert "{"))` but no one does what I want.

What am I missing?

I *have* activated the electric behavior via `c-toggle-auto-newline` otherwise I wouldn't have gotten the newline inserted.

Comment: Could you show the effect you're looking for? Are you just asking how to insert a brace character? I suppose not...

Comment: I'm expecting the `{` to occur aswell.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying or trying to do. Hopefully someone does. I guess you're trying to insert a `{` char and is not inserting. Did you try with `emacs -Q` (no init file), and with just `(insert "{")`?

Comment: I want programmatic calls to insertion of "{" and "}" behave exact like interactive inserts when pressing the corresponding keys when `electric-indent-mode` is active in C-like modes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `c-electric-brace` is not designed to accept the character to be inserted as a function argument; instead, it just invokes `self-insert-command` which uses the variable `last-command-event` to decide which character to insert.  And of course just calling `self-insert-command` doesn't involve the C electric behavior at all.

You might try binding `last-command-event` explicitly, something like this:

```
(let ((last-command-event ?{)) (c-electric-brace nil))
```

Have a look at the "Command Loop Info" Info node in the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual for discussion of `last-command-event`.